# How to add custom dictionary to SyntaxNet?

Tags: parsing, tensorflow, pos-tagger, syntaxnet

Is there any way to add user-defined vocabulary to improve Parsey McParseface's pos-tagging performance?

In other words, how can I teach newly-coined words to my parsey's cousin?

I know I can manually add CONLL-U formatted sentences with the new vocabs to my training corpus... but that might take so long.